# Vue how to get duration of each youtube video in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, youtube-api

In my `vue`-app I'm using the [VueToube](https://github.com/anteriovieira/vue-youtube)-package. So far it works fine, but I want to display the duration of each video so I tried to do this:

```
<div v-for="(review, index) in reviews" :key="index">
   <youtube
      :video-id="video"
      :width="420"
      :ref="'video' + index"
      @ready="ready"
    ></youtube>
    <div>
      {{ time }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I'm doing this:

```
data(){
  time: '00:00'
},
methods: {
  ready(player) {

  Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach((el) => {
    this.$refs[el][0].player.getDuration().then((result) => {
      this.videoDuration(result);
    });
  });
},
videoDuration(time) {
  time = Math.round(time);
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time - minutes * 60;

  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

  this.time =  minutes + ":" + seconds;
},
```

This does not really work since the results is each video having the same length/duration.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Time will always be the last time calculated. Make it an array and use the index of the loop to access the value. `this.time.push(minues + ":" + seconds)` and then when you print it `{{ time[index] }}`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Hmm yes, since I have 4 videos, it returns an array with 16 entries... :-/